# What are the drawbacks of having singleton quartz jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Quartz assumes that all job executions will happen in a new instance of the job class.

But why is that needed? What will happen if I plug a `JobFactory` that returns the same instance everytime it is called? Apart from the fact that jobs won't be able to use instance fields safely.

Comment: May be it would be costlier to hold all the services bean's reference for a job which is made to run yearly

Comment: yearly - perhaps. But it's likely that most jobs will run in shorter intervals.

Comment: well there should be optional configuration for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a JobFactory would be just fine, so long as all of your job classes are written to be thread safe.